# Single Click Not Working , Double Click Works

Tags: android, onclick, double-click, focusable

I am working on an android application . I am facing a strange issue . On one particular device (**Micromax** **doodle** **3**) single click is not working . I have to do double click .

Basically what is happening is when i click on some list item or any button it does not call **onclick** .When i click again it works .

Basically every second click is working . suppose i click anywhere in my app , it does not work . i click again it works .
Then i click again , it will not work . Now i click it works .

So first , third , fifth and so on these clicks are not working ..
while second , fourth , sixth and so on these clicks are working

Comment: Please post your code!!

Comment: if it works on other devices but Micromax, then it sounds like a device dependant problem.....

Comment: i am not sure what was the issue . But earlier my application was in full screen mode . i mean both navigation and status bar were hidden. But now i changed it to show both the bars .
And somehow the single click is working fine. I suppose i need to dig deeper to see whats the cause

Comment: may i know the reason for downvotes

Answer (score 0):

It can be happen because of TalkBack option is open. Making it off will solve the problem.

To Off it use following step

Go to device setting -> TalkBack the off it.

Comment: thats not the case here